# .PHONY all rules in GNU make file?

Tags: make

Am I wrong in my interpretation that I should basically just put first before all make rules:

```
.PHONY: all of my rules

all:
    echo "Executing all ..."

of:
    echo "Executing of ..."

my:
    echo "Executing my ..."

rules:
    echo "Executing rules ..."
```

Is there ever a case where you would not want to follow this 'formula'?

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Clark Grubb's [Makefile style guide](http://clarkgrubb.com/makefile-style-guide#phony-targets) recommends that:

> - All phony targets should be declared by making them prerequisites of .PHONY.
> - **add each phony target as a prerequisite of .PHONY immediately before the target declaration, rather than listing all the phony targets in a single place.**
> - No file targets should be prerequisites of .PHONY.
> - phony targets should not be prerequisites of file targets.

For your example, this would mean:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    echo "Executing all ..."

.PHONY: of
of:
    echo "Executing of ..."

.PHONY: my
my:
    echo "Executing my ..."

.PHONY: rules
rules:
    echo "Executing rules ..."
```

Multiple `PHONY` targets are allowed; see also this Stack Overflow question: ["Is it possible to have multiple .PHONY targets in a gnu makefile?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156382/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-phony-targets-in-a-gnu-makefile)

Also, while this isn't mentioned directly in your question, care must be taken not to have a `PHONY` target with the same name of an actual input or intermediate files in your project. Eg, if your project hypothetically had a source code file named `rules` (with no suffix), the inclusion of that string in a `PHONY` target could break expected `make` behavior.

Comment: excellent share on the style guide.  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a good practice to follow but fragmenting it and putting the fragments even after full rule recipes works too on my gmake (3.81):

E.g.:

```
#Makefile
all:
   @echo hello world
.PHONY: all
```

CMD:

```
$ touch all
$ make all    #this would be a no-op if all weren't a phoney target
  hello world
```